# Primefaces drag and drop with dynamic data

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, draggable

I'm quite new to primefaces and i ran to this issue with p:draggable commponent.
This is my web site using p:draggable component exactly as in primefaces showcases.

```
            <p:fieldset legend="PreparedData">

                <p:dataGrid id="currentData" columns="1" var="res" value="#{SomeBean.data}">
                    <p:column>
                        <p:panel id="draggedres" header="#{res.name}">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                                <h:outputText value="#{res.name}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>

                        </p:panel>
                        <p:draggable for="draggedres" />

                    </p:column>
                </p:dataGrid>
             </p:fieldset>
             <p:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{SomeBean.addItem}" update="currentData" />
```

Theres my bean SomeBean.

```
public class SomeBean{

    private List<SomeObjects> data = new ArrayList<SomeObjects>();

    public void addItem(){
        data.add(new SomeObjects("someName"));
    }

    //GETTERS SETTERS                 
}
```

Now the problem is that when i add new data to that List it appears BUT is not draggable. Only way how to make those data draggable is to set them into constructor of that bean.
Anyone know where did i make mistake? I already read Primefaces manual but theres nothing about it. In there they just silently assume that data will be set only from contructor.
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Tested your example, it is working fine in my environment. What version of primefaces, jsf, etc are you using? (mine was tested on primefaces 3.3.1)

Comment: PrimeFaces 3.4.1 Glassfish 3.1.2 JSF 2.0

Comment: hmm u are right.. this really works on fresh page... must find out what wrong on my current page anyway thanks for answer

Comment: ok its functional now. i erased droppable and now its working so thanks Mindwin because your comment led me to solution.

Comment: well i want droppable there but we'll see if there will be a problem. I just thought that the problem was in draggable tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code you submitted is working just fine. Check the code you are using, sometimes in an attempt to obfuscate code data (like variable names, package names that could contain sensitive info), we omit or alter something related to the bug at hand.

This is the code (ipsis literis) I used to test your example:

SomeBean.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeBean {
private List<SomeObjects> data = new ArrayList<SomeObjects>();


public void addItem(){
data.add(new SomeObjects("someName"));
}


public List<SomeObjects> getData() {
    return data;
}


public void setData(List<SomeObjects> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}
```

SomeObject.java

```
public class SomeObjects {

private String name;

public SomeObjects(String string) {
    this.setName(string);
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

}
```

draggable.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:separator styleClass="espacador" />
    <p:fieldset legend="PreparedData">
        <p:dataGrid id="currentData" columns="1" var="res" value="#{someBean.data}">
            <p:column>
                <p:panel id="draggedres" header="#{res.name}">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                        <h:outputText value="#{res.name}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
                <p:draggable for="draggedres" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataGrid>
    </p:fieldset>
    <p:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{someBean.addItem}" update="currentData" />
<h:body>
</html>
```